# Webpack: remove comments from development bundle generated by webpack itself

Tags: webpack

I just need to remove the comments without minifying the bundle generated by webpack itself.
Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6879#issuecomment-403428325 (though this is for the minimizer but could set you off on the right track)